# Get state of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, state, drawable, android-videoview

In my application I get multiple paths from the user (1 to an image, 1 to an audio track, and 1 to a video) and store them in a database.  When another Activity is started to view the files, there isn't a guarantee the files will still be at those paths or even exist at all, since the user chose them and may have deleted/moved them.  Therefore, I need to be able to check if the files at those paths are valid.
My original plan was to simply catch any Exceptions thrown when constructing + setting up each object.
Here's what I'm using to view each:

```
Image - a Drawable
Audio - a MediaPlayer
Video - a VideoView
```

I would have handled each Exception by showing a dialog to the user
However, no Exceptions are thrown and instead I get different error messages

The VideoView shows its own dialog saying "Sorry, this video cannot be played"

The others go to LogCat:

```
04-10 23:34:43.174: ERROR/PlayerDriver(30): Command PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNotSupported
04-10 23:34:43.174: ERROR/MediaPlayer(271): error (1, -4)
04-10 23:34:43.365: ERROR/MediaPlayer(271): Error (1,-4)
```

Any thoughts on how to get the state of MediaPlayer and VideoView or some other way to check the paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `OnErrorListener` for `VideoView` and for `MediaPlayer`. If an error occurs - your listener will be called. Also, you can check both audio and video using `MediaPlayer` or using `VideoView` since it contains `MediaPlayer` to handle both anyway.

BTW, I *think* that the listener of `VideoView` is actually set in the `MediaPlayer` object within the `VideoView`